# Rails 5 API Key Pair Design Pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, design-patterns

How do I make my Rails 5 API-only work with key pairs pattern? I can't consider JWT because of these requirements

I want to:

- Keep track of the apps using the API
- Securely verify the resources ownership without username/password.

I could think of this process:

- User create new app in our webapp.
- The system generates a secured public key (the app identifier) and a private key
- User can use the key-pair to integrate the API with their apps in different languages as long as they can submit the HTTP request.
- The server will verify their key-pair and respond accordingly.

My questions:

- Is there any gem to handle key-pair generating? (just for references)
- I would prefer to generate the key-pair myself rather than using a gem. What algorithm best suits my requirements?
- Should I expire the key-pair?

Comment: Rails 5 ships with [`has_secure_token`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html) that you can use to generate tokens. The expiration is dependent on your application and user experience.

Comment: Is that something secured enough to use for the private key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is there any gem to handle key-pair generating? (just for references)

  You can just create a table to do the mapping yourself. Create unique constraint on the combination of them

  ```
  -------------------------
  | id          | INT     |
  -------------------------
  | public_key  | VARCHAR |
  -------------------------
  | private_key | VARCHAR |
  -------------------------
  | user_id     | INT     |
  -------------------------
  ```
- I would prefer to generate the key-pair myself rather than using a
  gem. What algorithm best suits my requirements?

  Not recommended. Even if you can do a better job than a proven gem (not likely), it doesn't worth the time unless you have a really really good reason or there are fundamental flaws in all the gems and they will cause issues in your use case. But if you do want to, you can utilize a fast hashing algorithm like [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [Murmurhash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) and build on top of them.

  You can simply use [`SecureRandom`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) which is shipped with ruby already. Example use case:

  ```
  SecureRandom.uuid #=> "2d931510-d99f-494a-8c67-87feb05e1594"
  ```
- Should I expire the key-pair?

  This depends on how your key-pair is used. If your users depend on the key to make api call to your app, mostly likely no. Imagine, your app depends on Google's API, and one day, out of nowhere, Google expired your key and all your API calls return 403. whoops... But you would want to give users the option to revoke and regenerate them.

  Good example is Facebook, Google, or even payment services like Stripe, Braintree don't expire your key-pair unless you revoke it.

  Or if you do want to do expiration, you should provide a refresh mechanism. You can take a look at [Uber's oauth API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#refreshing-tokens).
- Do I need to securely generate the app id (I call public key)? Can it just be random?

  So I assume what you meant by public and private key pair is not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). If not, you first need to know what endpoint you are are going to expose.

  If your users will hit your API endpoint only from the server side, then you just need one secret key. Then you can simply look for the user by the secret key, and then confirm the identity. In most cases, this is what you need.

  If your users also need to make requests from the frontend (e.g. google's address validation API, stripe's credit card validation API etc), you will need a publishable key (because it will be in the frontend codebase). With this, you will need to be more careful with what you return. A rule of thumb is, if the information is sensitive (like stripe), you want to return something client specific. For example, you validate a credit card and return the card token. The token should be unique to a specific client. See below. You return a different token even they are the same credit card. When the client actually make a request to charge the credit card, you look for the client using the secret key, then match the card token.

  ```
        publishable_keys                      credit_card_tokens
  -----------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------
  | publishable_key | secret_key | app_id |    | app_id | card_token | credit_card_id |
  -----------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------
  |   public_12345  | private_12 |    1   |    |   1    |   cc_1233  |       1        |
  -----------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------
  |   public_23456  | private_23 |    2   |    |   2    |   cc_2344  |       1        |
  -----------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------
  ```

Comment: `SecureRandom` with base64 sounds ideal for the secret key. Do I need to securely generate the app id (I call public key)?

Comment: @ln9187 not quite sure what you meant by securely generating the app id. can you clarify?

Comment: For sure we need a secured secret key (private_key), what about public_key, can it just be random?

Comment: @ln9187 please see my edit, the last point. let me know if you have question.